# Why would a C compiler not precompute static values?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have some code that I was debugging and I noticed that the compiler (MIPS gcc-4.7.2) is not pre-calculating certain values that I would expect to just a static value in memory.  Here's the crux of the code that is causing what I am seeing:

```
#define SAMPLES_DATA 500
#define VECTORX 12
#define VECTORY 18

(int *)calloc(SAMPLES_DATA * VECTORX * VECTORY, sizeof(int));
```

In the assembly, I see that these values are multiplied as (500*12*18) instead of a static value of 108000.  This is only an issue because I have some code that runs in realtime where these defines are used to calculate the offsets into an array and the same behavior is seen.  I only noticed because the time to write to memory was taking much longer than expected on the hardware.  I currently have a "hot fix" that is a function that uses assembly, but I'd rather not push that into production.

Is this standard gcc compiler behavior?  If so, is there some way to force or create a construction that precomputes these static multiplication values?

**edit:**
I'm compiling with -O2; however, the build chain is *huge*.  I don't see anything on the commands being generated by the Makefile that are unusual.

**edit:** 
The issue seems to not be present when gcc 5 is used.  Whatever is causing my issue, seems to not carry on to later versions.

Comment: Hmmm... did you try different optimization levels? (though I think the compiler itself should do the calculation even at the lowest level)

Comment: That looks weird, gcc usually does constant folding well. Are you sure you turned on the optimizer? Do you have a small compilable example to show?

Comment: It's even stranger if we consider that GCC can't even avoid constant folding, even when we want it (it does it at a very early stage of compilation). [Here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6hVnjF)'s what I got with MIPS gcc 5.4. Notice the `OR`ing of `65536` and `0xa5e0` which is exactly your constant, not the separate multipliers.

Comment: @Ruslan Maybe it's just a quirk of 4.7.2.  I'll give it go with 5.4.

Comment: Does a `#define SIZE_ARR SAMPLES_DATA * VECTORX * VECTORY` make any difference?

Comment: It's all working well with 5.4.  I will just stop digging at this point.  Thank you for looking.

Comment: Is int 16-bit or 32-bit on this platform?

Comment: @M.M It's 32-bits